# Cookie set and redirection issue PHP and .Net application

Tags: php, .net, redirect, cookies, setcookie

I'm using cookie to communicate between .net and php application.
I'm able to retrieve cookie value using php and the cookie is set using .net
So in both files, i can view the cookie values.

What i want to do now is.

If the user is logged in using aspx application, then he is allowed to view the php pages(using cookie).
If not logged in, they will be redirected to aspx page.

Here is the code

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE["AuthoerCode"])){
   header("Location:login.aspx");
}else{
  header("Location:dashboard.php");
}
```

The above if conditions works perfect but the else part is not working and I'm getting this error.

```
The page isn't redirecting properly(Firefox)
```

In other words, i need to check in my dashboard.php page whether the cookie is set or not - If set, view the dashboard.php else view the login.aspx

Where is the problem now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give full server path for it,

for example

`if (!isset($_COOKIE["AuthoerCode"])){
    $url = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/login.aspx";
    header("Location: ". $url);
}else{
$url = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/dashboard.php"; // HERE PUT your php file's full path. you can able to access it if it also on another server.
    header("Location:".$url);
}`

Comment: even i have tried with full path . it is showing the same error. any help

Comment: Is the different server? or the same server?

Comment: same server only i am using

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are not in a loop. Your dashboard page may be redirecting you back to the current  page where you are checking cookie